# Deleting new'd memory in a std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Say I have a map of pointers that I `new`, how can I iterate through this map and delete them cleanly? Here's what I've tried:

```
std::map<std::string, Foo*> foos;
foos.insert(std::make_pair("blah", new Foo()));

for (auto& f : foos) {
    delete f;
}
```

Though it doesn't seem to work, I get the following error.

```
$ g++ test.c -std=c++14
test.c: In function 'int main()':
test.c:12:12: error: type 'struct std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Foo*>' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer
     delete f;
```

Comment: Use smart pointers and let them handle it.

Comment: Okay, but what if I don't want to use smart pointers?

Comment: @Jee, than don't use them.

Comment: @user2807083 That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Jee Your code creates a leak if `blah` already exists as a key. since `insert` will not insert the data into the map.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @Jee If the key already exists, `insert` will not insert the data into the map.  That leaves you with an allocated object that you have no way of recovering, thus the leak.  Please read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ah okay, the more you know. Luckily in this specific code I am manually inserting entries -- so no duplicate entries.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `std::map` contains key-values pairs.  Thus when you do

```
for (auto& f : foos) {
    delete f;
}
```

`f` is a pair and not the pointer that you stored in the map.  You cannot call `delete` on that pair as you did not allocate it.  If you wan to delete all of the pointers in the map then you can use

```
for (auto& f : foos) {
    delete f.second;
}
foos.clear();
```

This will delete every pointer in the map and then the `clear()` call will empty the map so you do not have a map full of deleted pointers.

I do suggest though that you use plain values if you can and if not then at least use smart pointers.  They will handle the memory deallocation for you.

Answer (score 2):

The map element is a `std::pair` of key and value, so in this case you should delete its `second` field:

```
std::map<std::string, Foo*> foos;
foos.insert("blah", new Foo());

for (auto& f : foos) {
    delete f.second;
}
```